# Python Ceasar Cypher help a level

Tags: python

Can someone help me figure out how to keep all of the letters of the encrypted sentence on the same line. The code works, although lengthy ha.

```
sentence = raw_input('Enter a sentence to be encrypted ')
shift = input('Enter a shift value ')

def createDict (shift):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .,'
    alphaList=[]

    for letter in alphabet:
        alphaList.append(letter)
    alphaDict={}
    for letter in alphaList:
        valueLetterIndex = (alphaList.index(letter) + shift)%len(alphaList)
        valueLetter = alphaList[valueLetterIndex]
        alphaDict[letter] = valueLetter
    return alphaDict

def encryptText(sentence, shift):
    dict = createDict(shift)
    for letter in sentence:
        encryptC = dict [letter]
        print encryptC

print encryptText(sentence, shift)
```

Comment: Can you show us what it is currently outputting?

Comment: No need to loop over `alphabet` to create `alphaList`. Simply `alphaList = list(alphabet)` would do. Even better, discard `alphaList` altogether and use `alphabet` directly.

Comment: Its outputing whatever the user inputs e.g. a sentence to be shifted by a certain value, but it isn't on the same line and thats all i need to do to finish this problem, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Collect your encrypted characters in a list, then print the joined result:

```
def encryptText(sentence, shift):
    encryptionmap = createDict(shift)
    output = []
    for letter in sentence:
        output.append(encryptionmap[letter])
    print ''.join(output)
```

I renamed your `dict` variable to `map` to avoid masking the built-in `dict` type.

Your `createDict` function could be simplified to:

```
def createDict (shift):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .,'

    alphaDict = {}
    for pos, letter in enumerate(alphabet):
        valueLetterIndex = (pos + shift) % len(alphabet)
        valueLetter = alphabet[valueLetterIndex]
        alphaDict[letter] = valueLetter
    return alphaDict
```

Because a string is a sequence just like a list; no need to convert to a list first. By using `enumerate` we save ourselves the bother of having to look up the index of each letter.

Comment: `alphabet` could be `alphabet = string.letters+' .,'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some shorter "pythonic" code since you mentioned the length.

```
def createDict (shift):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .,'
    L = len(alphabet)

    return dict( (letter, alphabet[(i + shift) % L]) 
                    for i, letter in enumerate(alphabet))    

def encryptText(sentence, shift):
    D = createDict(shift)
    return ''.join(D[l] for l in sentence)
```